# IIS application cannot access path despite giving "Everyone" access

Tags: c#, iis-7

An IIS application seems to have trouble writing to a temporary folder (it's needed to make use of Excel Interop).

> Access to the path 'C:\Temp\temp_file_name.xlsx' is denied.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path 'C:\Temp\temp_file_name.xlsx' is denied.

Here's the Stack Trace:

```
 [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Temp\temp_file_name.xlsx' is denied.]
    System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +10550675
    System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite) +863
    System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName) +12
    ExcelOperations.FileHelper.CopyFile(String sourcePath, String destinationPath) +477
    WebExtensions.PersonalPriceListDataExchange.CreateNewQueryBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +427
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

Now, by all accounts, this looks like a typical "lack of permissions" case, but I've already modified the Temp folder to allow the special group "Everyone" full access...

What could be missing?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention!

The application WORKS when I log in to the site using an administrative account. However, any other account (despite logging into the IIS site successfully) doesn't have access to that folder. Again, the weird thing is that I've granted "Everyone" full access, and it's still not working.

The application in question is a MS CRM 4.0 extension (residing inside the CRM ISV folder so it's a subsite), using the same application pool as CRM itself. However, I have some doubts if this is in any way related to CRM itself. I think it's likely an IIS / permissions issue.

**EDIT 2:**

I've added a simple piece of code to my application:

```
        throw new Exception(Page.User.Identity.Name + " " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

Obviously, this throws the current name of the currently used identity. The identity is fine - i.e. it's a normal user belonging to the domain. I can even add this specific user and give him permissions for the folder, and **it still fails**. :(

**EDIT 3:**

I've turned on auditing for the temp folder.

Here are the results (I had to edit some information out):

```
A handle to an object was requested.

Subject:
Security ID:        -the domain and login of the currently logged user-
Account Name:       -the current username-
Account Domain:     -the current domain-
Logon ID:       0x5e3194d

Object:
Object Server:      Security
Object Type:        File
Object Name:        C:\Temp\temp_file_name.xlsx
Handle ID:      0x0

Process Information:
Process ID:     0x13f0
Process Name:       C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe

Access Request Information:
Transaction ID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Accesses:       DELETE
            READ_CONTROL
            SYNCHRONIZE
            ReadData (or ListDirectory)
            WriteData (or AddFile)
            AppendData (or AddSubdirectory or CreatePipeInstance)
            WriteEA
            ReadAttributes
            WriteAttributes

Access Reasons:     DELETE: Unknown or unchecked
            READ_CONTROL:   Unknown or unchecked
            SYNCHRONIZE:    Unknown or unchecked
            ReadData (or ListDirectory):    Unknown or unchecked
            WriteData (or AddFile): Denied by Integrity Policy check
            AppendData (or AddSubdirectory or CreatePipeInstance):  Unknown or unchecked
            WriteEA:    Unknown or unchecked
            ReadAttributes: Unknown or unchecked
            WriteAttributes:    Unknown or unchecked

Access Mask:        0x130197
Privileges Used for Access Check:   -
Restricted SID Count:   0
```

The user specified in the audit report **was given full access to the folder**.

Comment: What is the filename of your file? It seems you are trying to write a '<file name>' ? The < and > characters are not allowed in a filename.

Comment: I've obviously cleared out the filename from the exception as I can't share too much of what I'm working on. It's a normal, Excel file name.

Comment: Have you tried to restart IIS?

Comment: Sorry, don't think it's too obvious though, what is so secret about a Excel filename? And I think it's worth mentioning because with the replacements you made you are creating illegal filenames which could be part of your problem.

Comment: *sigh* The filename contains, for one, the name of the client. I think this is enough to hide the filename. It does NOT contain illegal characters.

Comment: @Steve Yes, many times.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Someone edited my question, which caused the filenames to be hidden entirely, which may have been weird. I've edited the question to make it clear. Again, the actual filename isn't the problem.

Comment: Just curious - which file is failing, the source or the dest?

Comment: The destination. I'm assuming the application has correct read access.

Comment: Your app is using Windows Authentication?

Comment: My app (well, not really... we took it over ;P) is actually an extension application attached to MS CRM 4 (ISV folder), running using the same application pool as CRM itself. So, yes, Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, while I still don't know **why** exactly I couldn't access the folder in the described scenario, turning off impersonation access for the IIS application helped.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some thoughts...

- Obviously, giving Everyone access to the folder is bad. You should check the credentials under which your application pool is working. For example, if it's "Application pool identity" you only need to grant the user named something like IUSR access to the folder.
- One of the weird errors is that the error you're seeing could also be a result of attempting to write an empty file (zero bytes). I recall having the "permissions" issue that in fact turned out to be zero-byte file write.
- It's strange how the application user login changes the behaviour of the service access - are you doing impersonations? i.e. do you propagate the windows login to the service? If so - it could be that the error is because user is from another domain. For example, if user is from domain MYDOM, I think that the Everyone group has to be from that domain as well (take note that there are also "local domains", like your PC name - for example, MYPC\Administrator is local user and doesn't have anything with MYDOMAIN\Administrator).
- Ultimately, you might want to change the location of your Temp folder. You're using C#, so something like:

  `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()`

could do the trick, since the IIS already has a predefined path just for these purposes where you'll have write access. Needless to say, it's better practice than using `C:\Temp` which brings in serious security risks.

Comment: I will DEFINITELY try `GetTempPath()` - I've completely forgot about that. But, regarding the other ideas... if it doesn't work for Everyone, why would it work for a specific user? The error occurs when the file is being copied (`File.Copy(source, destination)`), so it's not a 0-byte file. Yes, there might be impersonation going on - this is CRM's doing I guess. But the users are from the same domain - otherwise they couldn't log into the CRM to begin with.

Comment: Using `GetTempPath()` yielded `C:\Windows\Temp`, and I also had no write access there. :(

Comment: Have you tried turning on extensive auditing on the folder? (on the folder properties/security tab/advanced/auditing...) it's a long shot, but it might give you some hint who's trying to do what, ie which credentials are being used and/or maybe why it's failing... or if the app is able to reach the folder at all...

Comment: The Auditing is a good idea - I've added the results to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to give admin permission to your apppool . it will solve all your problems .

Comment: While I'd love to do that, I'd rather have, in the end, a secure system, not an insecure one. Adding the administrator as the app-pool identity sounds like a bad idea. I can definitely do that for testing purposes, however.

Comment: yes , do it for testing purpose . but i think if you are doing ms office related coding then you might face lot of problem related to permission .

Comment: I am quite aware of this. I wanted to change the code to use OpenXML library instead of the Interop BUT the Excel document which is being modified turned out to be a lot more complex, and modifications using OpenXML do not refresh all the linked cells in the document.

Comment: I've tried using a system account. No change and the problem persists.

Comment: hey I new that i already faced same issue earlier . Instead use http://netoffice.codeplex.com/ to make excel doc . it will not create any permission issue at the time of hosting .

Comment: Alas, the problem is that I need to modify an existing Excel document. I COULD do that using the OpenXML library, but because the document is complex, some cells (which rely on the cells I update) don't get refreshed for end user. Using Excel means this problem doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance did you have both Anonymous and Windows Authentication enabled? Would help explain why it worked when Impersonation was turned off.

Comment: No - it had Windows Authentication and Impersonation enabled. Removing Impersonation and relying solely on Windows Authentication cleared things up (albeit now file access is based solely on the application pool identity, but that isn't a problem in this case).